# Showing full map on smaller screens in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to make my app `responsive` for smaller screens. On bigger screens, I have the `<List>` buttons for large screens but when the screen size is xs(mobile), I want that the whole screen should be covered with the `map`. I am able to hide the `list` in smaller screens but since I am using map width to be `80%` the sm screens only cover 80% for the map and 20% is just white screen. How can I bring the map to 100% on sm screen
...

```
import React from "react";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import "./styles.css";
import Icon from "../src/icon.png";
import shadow from "../src/shadow.png";
import Hidden from "@material-ui/core/Hidden";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      location: [
        {
          id: 1,
          machine: 1,
          lat: 51.503,
          lng: -0.091
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          machine: 2,
          lat: 51.543,
          lng: -0.051
        }
      ],
      center: [51.505, -0.091],
      zoom: 11,
      marker: null
    };
    this.clickAction = this.clickAction.bind(this);
  }

  Icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: Icon,
    shadowUrl: shadow,
    iconSize: [38, 50],
    shadowSize: [50, 64],
    iconAnchor: [22, 34], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
  });

  openPopUp(marker, id) {
    if (marker && marker.leafletElement) {
      marker.leafletElement.openPopup(id);
    }
  }

  clickAction(id, lat, lng) {
    this.setState({ marker: id, zoom: 16, center: [lat, lng] });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          {this.state.location &&
            this.state.location.map(location => {
              return location !== null ? (
                <Marker
                  position={[location?.lat, location?.lng]}
                  icon={this.Icon}
                  ref={this.openPopUp(location?.id)}
                >
                  <Popup> {location?.id} </Popup>
                </Marker>
              ) : null;
            })}
        </Map>

        {
          <Hidden smDown>
            <List style={{ width: "20%", float: "left" }}>
              {this.state.location &&
                this.state.location.map(({ id, machine, lat, lng }) => {
                  return (
                    <ListItem
                      key={id}
                      button
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.clickAction(id, lat, lng);
                      }}
                    >
                      Id {id} <br />
                      machine {machine}
                    </ListItem>
                  );
                })}
            </List>
          </Hidden>
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}

}
```

...
my sample is https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-star-m42qe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it seems like you are missing units in the width of `.leaflet-container`, this seems to be working fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tu-yq03h?file=/src/styles.css:106-109)

Comment: In your solution, list is being displayed after the maps. What I want is that list should cover 20% and maps should cover 80% in big and medium screens while in sm screen only the map covers the screen.

Comment: Made changes in the same code sandbox project, I have applied the media query in CSS